# useInfiniteQuery's enabled option in React Query doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I got the tagsList with this query, and "enabled: !!points" worked properly.

```
  const {
    data: tagsList,
    isLoading,
    isFetched,
  } = useQuery(EDiscountEndPoints.tags.key, discountEndpoints.tags, {
    enabled: !!points,
    onSuccess: (res) => {
      const currentCityId = searchParams.get('cityId');
      const currentTabId = searchParams.get('dTabId');
      const firstCity = res.tags.find((item) => {
        if (!!currentCityId) {
          return item.id === parseInt(currentCityId);
        } else {
          return item.name === 'city';
        }
      });
      const firstTab = currentTabId || 0;

      if (firstCity) {
        searchParams.set('cityId', `${firstCity.id}`);
        searchParams.set('dTabId', `${firstTab}`);
        setSearchParams(searchParams);
        setCurrentCity({
          label: firstCity.value,
          cityId: firstCity?.id,
        });
      }
      typeof points?.userPoint?.availablePoint === 'number' &&
        setSelectedPoint(Math.floor(points?.userPoint?.availablePoint / 2));
    },
  });
```

after this, I used useInfiniteQuery with this condition.

```
enabled: !!currentCity && typeof selectedPoint !== 'undefined'
```

or

```
enabled: !!tagsList.length
```

```
const {
    data: discounts,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isFetching,
    refetch,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(
    [EDiscountEndPoints.filteredList.key],
    (originParams) => {
      const tabs = tagsList?.tags.filter((item) => item.name !== 'city');
      return discountEndpoints.filteredList(originParams, {
        tags: [
          // ...(!!currentCity ? [currentCity.cityId] : []),
          ...(!!searchParams.get('cityId')
            ? [parseInt(searchParams.get('cityId') as string)]
            : []),
          ...(!!searchParams.get('dTabId') && !!tabs?.length
            ? [tabs[parseInt(searchParams.get('dTabId') as string)].id]
            : []),
        ],
        pointsTo: !!selectedPoint ? selectedPoint : 0,
      });
    },
    {
      // enabled: !!currentCity && typeof selectedPoint !== 'undefined',
      enabled: false,
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
        if (pages.length < lastPage.totalPages) {
          return {
            pagination: {
              page: pages.length,
              perPage: 10,
            },
          };
        } else {
          undefined;
        }
      },
      cacheTime: 0,
    }
  );
```

but useInfiniteQuery's enabled option didn't work and the query was called in every condition, even when enabled = false.

in react-query's documentation, it has been mentioned that
"The options for useInfiniteQuery are identical to the useQuery hook with the addition of the following...."
So i think the enabled option in useInfiniteQuery should work like useQuery.

"

Comment: yes, it should work like in useQuery. can you show this behaviour in a codesandbox reproduction ?

Comment: @TkDodo Just ran into this. Alexey made a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-query-enabled-false-fetchnextpage-forked-fnse4n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: so is the issue that calling `fetchNextPage` will still fetch the next page even though the query is "disabled"? I did not get that from the initial issue, thanks for the reproduction. I think this is kinda intended, like you can also call `refetch` and it will bypass enabled. What enabled can disable is mostly the automatic fetches, and the ones that would target it incidentally, like invalidation. You have it under control to just _not_ invoke that function if the query is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and have found that it was fetchNextPage() that triggered fetching despite {enabled: false} option.

You can add a condition whenever you use fetchNextPage(), e. g.

```
if ( !!currentCity && typeof selectedPoint !== 'undefined' ) {
    fetchNextPage()
}
```

Although I didn't find exactly this case in the documentation, it seems that one could rely on [the description of "refetch" behavior](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries). Anyway, I made a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-query-enabled-false-fetchnextpage-r2vzh7) to test how this stuff works.

Answer (score 1):

A proper solution to detecting a disabled query is to build logic based on the rules presented in the docs: [Disabling/Pausing Queries](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/disabling-queries)

> When enabled is `false`:
>
> - If the query has cached data, then the query will be initialized in the `status === 'success'` or `isSuccess` state.
> - If the query does not have cached data, then the query will start in the `status === 'loading'` and `fetchStatus === 'idle'` state.

Accordingly, you need a check like this:

```
if (query.status === 'loading' && query.fetchStatus === 'idle') {
   // is disabled
} else {
  // is enabled
  query.fetchNextPage();
}
```